# convert query from sql to oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
@weekenddtm = CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DD,(7 - DATEPART(DW,@p_end_dtm)),@p_end_dtm),111)
```

and I tried converting it into oracle using this query:

```
v_weekenddtm   := CAST(p_end_dtm + NUMTODSINTERVAL((7-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(p_end_dtm,'D'))),'DAY')  AS DATE);
```

,but it is giving me error. Any idea how to go ahead?

Comment: How do you want to "convert from sql" ?? Oracle - like all major RDBMS - uses SQL, too. SQL is the data query and data definition language for all major database systems......

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also, rather than "an error" it woul dhelp if you copied and pasted the error message.

Comment: "*from SQL to Oracle*" does not make sense. Oracle uses SQL as their its language - just like every other relational database. You should also explain what the (presumably) T-SQL code is doing for those that know Oracle but not SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

What are the datatypes of p_end_dtm and v_weekend_dtm?  Your code works if they are as follows:

```
declare
   p_end_dtm timestamp;
   v_weekend_dtm date;
begin
   v_weekend_dtm := CAST(p_end_dtm+ NUMTODSINTERVAL((7-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(p_end_dtm,'D'))),'DAY')  AS DATE);
end;
```